# how to shift grid in netcdf file from (-180, 180) to (0, 360) in python?

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I'm a obvious newbie to netCDF and some libraries in python.
What i've been struggling to is, I want to change longitude grid in netCDF file. It's like (-180, 180) but I have to change it to (0, 360).

In this case, I would have used 'shiftgrid' which could have been used with 'from mpl_toolkits.basemap import shiftgrid'.

But this mpl_toolkits.basemap is a troublesome to me. It's impossible to use this one..
So I'd like to solve this problem with cartopy or other things, you guys can see the libraries that I normally use at the bottom.

How can I change the grid thing?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pylot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import shiftgrid
from sys import exit    
import numpy as np
import pickle

file1= '/home/HadISST_sst.nc'
DATA1 = Dataset(file1, 'r')

hd_lat = DATA1.variables['latitude'][:] #89.5 -89.5
hd_lon0 = DATA1.variables['longitude'][:] #-179.5 179.5 
hd_sst0 = DATA1.variables['sst'][1320:,:,:] #time, y, x
DATA1.close()

# shift grid from (-180,180) to (0,360)
hd_sst, hd_lon = shiftgrid(0, hd_sst0, hd_lon0, start=True)
hd_lon2, hd_lat2 = np.meshgrid(hd_lon, hd_lat) # to 2d data
```

Answer (score 0):

Basemap and netCDF are libraries which you should not use any more.
[Xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/) and Cartopy are much better to handle climate data. (some examples: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/visualization_gallery.html)

You can change the grid like this:

```
import xarray as xr
your_data = xr.open_dataset('path/to/file.nc')
your_data['lon'] = your_data.lon + 180
```

Comment: That's not good... your data is shifted to the opposite side of the globe. Need to be using `numpy.mod(your_data.lon, 360)`.